# Finding all solutions of $\ddot{x} + a_1\dot{x}+a_2x = f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a linear inhomogeous differential equation of second order, so something of the form

\begin{align}
\ddot{x} + a_1\dot{x}+a_2x = f(t),
\end{align}

where it is given that $x_1(t) = 1$, $x_2(t) = t$ as well as $x_3(t) = t^2$ are solutions.

Is there a way to compute *all* the solutions of the differential equation above *without* actually trying to figure out the exact form of the differential equation?

Comment: "without actually trying to figure out the exact form of the differential equation?" But it's rather easy to find $f$ and the $a_i$. Why avoid it?

Comment: I agree. However, the problem states that it is not necessary, so that's why I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of the homogeneous equation
$$
\ddot{x}+a_1 \dot{x} + a_2 x = 0
$$
has to be
$$
t \mapsto c_1 x_1(t) + c_2 x_2(t), \quad c_1 \in \mathbb{R},~c_2 \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
Also note that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent functions and it is a known fact the homogeneous solution space is as maximum of dimension 2 (because the second derivative is the highest one). Expressions of the form $t \mapsto t^2$ can only appear in a homogeneous solution if the third derivative is involved in the differential equation. There is a closed formula for the solution that involves finding the root of a polynomial. You can read about this e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients).

Our case is the one in which the polynomial only has the root zero, meaning that it is of multiplicity 2. You can deduce this from the fact that there are no $e^\lambda$ expressions in the general homogeneous solution. Once again, you have to know the formula for this.

This means that $x_3$ is a particular solution of
$$
\ddot{x}+a_1 \dot{x} + a_2 x = f.
$$
So the general solution is of the form
$$
t \mapsto c_1 x_1(t) + c_2 x_2(t) + x_3(t), \quad c_1 \in \mathbb{R},~c_2 \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given two solutions $x,y$, we also get, for any $s\in\Bbb R$, that
$$
sx(t) +(1-s)y(t)
$$
is a solution. You have *three* linearly independent (over $\Bbb R$) solutions. This gives you the ability to generate all solutions in a similar manner.